# How much data I can send by Node.JS server per second?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine

I have tick based server and client in `Unity3D`. Server sending data to clients. `Middleware` is `NodeJS` server.
My question is how much data I can transfer every tick (I have 25 Ticks per second now) before server start `unsync` itself and clients starts to getting data late? I am sending just `JSON` strings.

Now I am sending about 1kB of data every tick. Its too much or its ok for `NodeJs` to server this to clients every tick?

I am counting that when I have 100 clients connected and 1kB/tick, I need fom `NodeJs` server to serve 2,44MB/s. I mean, internet connection is not problem, but is this possible?

Comment: How fast is your server? How many servers in your server farm, if you have one? How fast is the backbone your service provider? And, how fast is your connection from your client to the node server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely be most dependent on the hardware you end up running the server on, if you can distribute the task among multiple processes/servers, and what protocol you're using to send the data.

The easiest way to test the hardware that you currently have would be running a simple benchmark.

I put together a quick project to do some benchmarking with Socket.io
https://github.com/briancw/socket-io-stress-test

You'll need a way to simulate connected clients. I have previously created a stress testing tool that may be useful for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/m65

It uses headless browsers, so it should be able to make actual websocket connections so you can simulate very realistically.

Comment: So there is not any physical limit what nodejs socketio server can serve. Its all about hardware and internet speed?

Comment: With sufficient hardware, running on a single machine that limit is going to be extremely high. If you can distribute this task to multiple instances, then of course you can scale out as much as you like.

Comment: So on fast 1 core Xeon processor, 4GB RAM and SSD + 1Gbps internet it will not be problem for nodejs to serve like 400MB/s to clients

Comment: I think you'll be fine there, but you should benchmark with your own data. I've been able to get better performance using libraries other than Socket.io, so I'd recommend trying a few.
I put together a simple repo to give you a starting place for doing some benchmarking with Socket.io specifically.
https://github.com/briancw/socket-io-stress-test

I'm just sending the same random bytes. It'd be better to replace that with your own data. You'll also need a way to simulate clients.
I actually developed a tool that might be useful for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/m65